# How do I gracefully close the Neo4j Console running in PowerShell in a background service?

Tags: powershell, neo4j

Apologies for the somewhat complex question, but we need to have Neo4j running under a different service account in Windows Server 2012. I have been able to set up a scheduled task for Powershell in Task Scheduler wherein I invoke the following PowerShell script:

```
Import-Module "D:\Apps\Neo4j\bin\Neo4j-Management.psd1";
Invoke-Neo4j console;
```

This launches Neo4j just fine. The challenge I have is that once it launches, the task shows as a running task, which I am able to end from Task Scheduler, but doing so does not appear to gracefully close the java service running in the background and release the lock on the database file.

As a result, if I try to launch another session from the command line or from the helper app, I get errors as the lock has not been released.

**Question:**

After starting Neo4j as a Powershell console app, how does one end the service properly?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/#powershell-module-import):

> To stop the server, issue Ctrl-C in the console window that was created by the command.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no console window for a service running in the background. I wonder if a second service with "stop" on the service might work, but the service does not seem to return an ID.